# How to show attribute as "readonly" in UML?

Tags: rest, model, uml, class-diagram

I want to describe some models of an API in a diagram. Is there a standard how to mark an attribute as `readonly`? These attributes are set by the system and cannot be modified by the API consumer.

Currently I abuse the class diagram notation for `private` and `public` attributes. But I am not satisfied with this.

Thanks for your thoughts :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The usual way when you interface coding you would make private properties and use getter/setter operations. You could also leave it on a more abstract level and simply stereotype them with `<<readonly>>` or `<<r/o>>`. And finally you could use an appropriate getter method.

[image]

**Edit** The current UML 2.5 spec states on p. 17

> Attributes: each specified by its name, type, and multiplicity, and any additional properties such as {readOnly}.

An example on how to use this is found on p. 113:

[image]

Comment: This could be an oportunity, i have now found a better solution. UML 2.0 says you can add properties like this {readOnly} to each attribute.

Comment: You are right. I missed that paragraph. Will make an update to my answer.

Comment: The second example is nice because it also illustrates a derived field (area) which uses the / access operator -- it is natural that such a field would be read-only!